# Legend for lattice histogram

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

I am looking for a legend in the top of the following plot a which describes the polygons and the blue point in the frames.

```
    require(lattice)
    grid<-data.frame(F=rnorm(1000),T=rep(c("A","B"),each=500))
    histogram(~F|T, data=grid, params=c(1,2)
            ,layout=c(2,1), xlab = "",ylab="",as.table=TRUE
            #,par.settings = list(superpose.polygons = list(col=c(4)))
            #,key = list(polygons = list(col=c(4)),space="top",columns=1
            #           ,text = list("text")
            #            )
            #, auto.key = list(polygons = TRUE,title = "Survived", columns = 1)
            ,type="density",breaks=40
            ,panel=function(x,params,...){
               panel.grid()
               panel.histogram(x,...,col=8)     
               lab<-format(params[panel.number()], digits=2, nsmall=2)
               panel.points(params[panel.number()],0,pch=16,col=4)
               panel.text(1, 0.05, labels = lab) 
              })
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, late answer.

The trick with this is that you have 2 text labels (one for the bars and other for the points), but you just have one rectangle (the bars) and one point in the legend. You can make this work by adding two `text=` arguments to your `key=` argument. `Lattice` will add the elements to the key in the same order that you list them in your code.

```
require(lattice)
grid<-data.frame(F=rnorm(1000),T=rep(c("A","B"),each=500))
histogram(~F|T, data=grid, params=c(1,2)
      ,layout=c(2,1), xlab = "",ylab="",as.table=TRUE


      ,key=list(space="top",          #puts key on top of panels
            rectangles=list(col=8),   #draws gray box
            text=list("gray bars"),   #label box
            points=list(col=4,pch=16), #draw blue point
            text=list("blue dots")    #label point
      )


      ,type="density",breaks=40
      ,panel=function(x,params,...){
        panel.grid()
        panel.histogram(x,...,col=8)     
        lab<-format(params[panel.number()], digits=2, nsmall=2)
        panel.points(params[panel.number()],0,pch=16,col=4)
        panel.text(1, 0.05, labels = lab) 
      })
```